# Error Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to recover this value from the database and send it to the webpage using a `JSP`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sessionParameters={};
sessionParameters.lat=<%=session.getAttribute("lat") %>
sessionParameters.lng=<%=session.getAttribute("lng") %>
sessionParameters.geometry=<%=session.getAttribute("geo")%>;
console.log(JSON.stringify(sessionParameters));//this line does not work
</script>
```

This is what the `Firebug` console reveals to me:

```
 var sessionParameters={};
 sessionParameters.lat=null
 sessionParameters.lng=null
 sessionParameters.geometry=nj|}CqzmoXuo_Tsbgv@dlfk@edwBbduHk}nr@hn`X~hkS;
 console.log(JSON.stringify(sessionParameters));//this line does not work
```

In Google Chrome console,I have this error:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } 
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined
```

The second error occurs when I try to do this:

```
 var params=window.sessionParameters;
 var path=loader.decodeShape(params.geometry);
 var pline=line.createPolyline(path,'#FF0000');
```

Comment: Maybe replace sessionParameters.geometry=nj|}CqzmoXuo_Tsbgv@dlfk@edwBbduHk}nr@hn`X~hkS; with sessionParameters.geometry='nj|}CqzmoXuo_Tsbgv@dlfk@edwBbduHk}nr@hn`X~hkS'; ? dont u need to escape that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're passing a string value to JavaScript, you need to enclose it in apostrophes or quotation marks.

```
sessionParameters.geometry = "<%=session.getAttribute("geo")%>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use quotes `"` and do something like this :

```
sessionParameters.geometry="nj|}CqzmoXuo_Tsbgv@dlfk@edwBbduHk}nr@hn`X~hkS";

sessionParameters.geometry="<%=session.getAttribute("geo")%>";
```